# Casting multiple values in R without dropping rows with duplicate IDs but different values

Tags: r, casting

I need to cast multiple values from this df:

```
test_df <- data.frame(ID=c("409_012", rep("409_003", 2)), 
  type=c("a", rep("b", 2)),
  val1=sample(1:10, 3),
  val2=sample(1:10, 3) )

       ID type val1 val2
1 409_012    a    5    9
2 409_003    b   10    2
3 409_003    b    2    3
```

To get the following df:

```
       ID   val1_a   val2_a   val1_b   val2_b
1 409_012        5        9       NA       NA
2 409_003       NA       NA       10        2
3 409_003       NA       NA        2        3
```

I have tried the following command, however I have multiple rows with ID 409_003 with different values which I need to retain as separate rows, and this ends up dropping a row and including them both in one row:

```
as.data.frame(tidyr::pivot_wider(test_df, names_from=type, values_from=c(val1, val2)))
```

And wrongly gives me this:

```
       ID val1_a val1_b val2_a val2_b
1 409_012      5   NULL      9   NULL
2 409_003   NULL  10, 2   NULL   2, 3
```

Can anyone help with this? If so would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add an `id` column to your data  (you can use `tibble::rowid_to_column()`) before pivoting.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Better:
Using `names_glue`

```
test_df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = type,
    values_from = c(val1, val2),
    names_glue = "{.value}_{type}"
  ) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
  ID      val1_a val1_b val2_a val2_b
  <chr>    <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 409_012      5     NA     10     NA
2 409_003     NA     10     NA      7
3 409_003     NA      7     NA      8
```

First answer:
One way could be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test_df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -c(ID, type)
  ) %>% 
  unite(names, c(name, type)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = names,
    values_from = value,
    values_fn = list
  ) %>% 
  unnest(c(val1_a, val2_a, val1_b, val2_b))
```

```
  ID      val1_a val2_a val1_b val2_b
  <chr>    <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 409_012      5     10     NA     NA
2 409_003     NA     NA     10      7
3 409_003     NA     NA      7      8
```

Comment: Thanks so much to you both, this is exactly what I needed!